# Convertir valores de un Array de objetos en mayúsculas Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, javascript-objeto

O soy un mal buscador, porque no hay respuestas en Google con respecto a este tema

```
productos:{
           0: {item:'laptop', marca:'lenovo'},
           1: {item:'impresora', marca:'hp'},
           2: {item:'mouse', marca:'genius'}
}
```

Tengo el siguiente objeto y requiero convertir los valores del objeto a Mayúsculas, veo muchos ejemplos de convertir el key en Mayúsculas etc. Pero no logro encontrar uno de valores.

El siguiente fragmento convierte el key de un objeto en minúsculas

```
    const lowercaseKeys = obj =>
    Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
        acc[key.toLowerCase()] = obj[key];
        return acc;
    }, {});

    // const productos = { Name: 'Adam', sUrnAME: 'Smith' };
    const myObjLower = lowercaseKeys(productos);
    console.warn(myObjLower);
```

Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con el siguiente fragmento de código. Simplemente iteras en el array con un reduce y vas agregando el valor de las propiedades convertidas a mayúscula con el método de string `toUpperCase()`

```js
const productos = {
  0: {item:'laptop', marca:'lenovo'},
  1: {item:'impresora', marca:'hp'},
  2: {item:'mouse', marca:'genius'}
}

const newProductos = Object.entries(productos).reduce((acc, producto) =>{
  producto[1].item = producto[1].item.toUpperCase()
  producto[1].marca = producto[1].marca.toUpperCase()
  acc[producto[0]] = producto[1]
  return acc
},{})

console.log(newProductos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola el mismo código le sirve solo tiene que usar `toUpperCase` para `obj[key]`

```js
const upperCaseValues = obj =>
    Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
        acc[key] = obj[key].toUpperCase(); // aquí
        return acc;
    }, {});

     const productos = [{item:'laptop', marca:'lenovo'},
           {item:'impresora', marca:'hp'},
           {item:'mouse', marca:'genius'}];
   var newProducts = [];
   for(var i in productos){
    const myObjLower = upperCaseValues (productos[i]);
    newProducts.push(myObjLower);
   }
    
    console.log(newProducts);
```

si quiere hacerlo para los key solo usar `toUpperCase` para el key

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Otro ejemplo de cómo hacerlo, más rápido de escribir y procesar, sería este:

```js
const productos = {
    0: {item:'laptop', marca:'lenovo'},
    1: {item:'impresora', marca:'hp'},
    2: {item:'mouse', marca:'genius'}
}


for (const [, value] of Object.entries(productos)) {
    Object.keys(value).forEach(key => value[key] = value[key].toUpperCase());
}

console.log(productos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Como hay que iterar varias veces, se puede hacer también una función recursiva que sirva para *n* niveles, ejemplo:

```js
const productos = {0: {item: 'laptop',marca: 'lenovo'}, 1: {item: 'impresora', marca: 'hp'}, 2: { item: 'mouse', marca: 'genius', otro_nivel: { otra_cosa: "cualquier_string_en_minuscula"} }}

function a_mayusculas(obj) {

  for (let k in obj) {

    if (typeof obj[k] === "string") {

      obj[k] = obj[k].toUpperCase(); // <-- siempre afecta el objeto original

    } else if (typeof obj[k] === "object") {

      a_mayusculas(obj[k]);

    }

  }

}

a_mayusculas(productos);

console.log(productos)
```